# PyCharm doesn't list Python 3.12 interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, pythoninterpreter

On my Pop OS system the base Python interpreter is 3.10, and I installed Python 3.12, it works perfectly fine:

[image: img1]

With 3.12 I can create virtual environment, run Python files, so it works perfectly:

[image]

But when I try to set it in PyCharm, it just doesn't see Python 3.12:

[image: img2]

So it sees and recognizes `python`, `python3`, `python3.10` binaries, but not `python3.12`, despite python3.12 being there:

[image]

Why is that? What should I do?

Comment: Did you try adding the 3.12 interpreter? See in the first screen, "Add interpreter" next to the interpreter selection dropdown?

Comment: Inside the "Add interpreter > Select Python Interpreter" dialog, try clicking the "refresh" button (second button from the right at the top). You may be looking at an outdated tree. Does `python3.12` appear after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I orignally downloaded Pycharm from snap store, and this version of Pycharm appears to be a bit outdatted and buggy.

I downloaded the newest version from the official website https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/?section=linux and it works flawlessly.